# Django accent insensitive ordering

Tags: django, postgresql, internationalization, django-queryset

I'm using Django 1.10 and PostgreSQL 9.5, and when trying to get an ordered queryset, I get words starting with an accented letter (like Á) after those starting with Z.

Is there a way to order a queryset in an accent insensitive way? I tried with unaccent, but it won't work.

Comment: If there is a way in postgres, you can run raw SQL in Django. That being said, an alternative might be to create a new column where you save the text without accents just for the ordering.

Comment: I thought about that, but I don't want to create a column just for sorting queries if I have an alternative. I think I'll give a try to the raw SQL.